# Missing assembly reference that IS there

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-ce, system.data.sqlite

So I was working on a Windows CE 3.5 project with SQLite and noticed I could not multi thread with this version. I downloaded and installed Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 3.5 SP1) from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

I copied the below to my project library and made a reference to the System.Data.SQLite.dll and Linq even though im not using Linq. Then I cleaned my project and rebuilt only to recieve these errors. Anyone have any Idea how to fix this problem?

```
System.Data.SQLite.dll
SQLite.Interop.dll
SQLite.Designer.dll
System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It says it needs a reference to ``System.Data``. Have you tried removing the reference and adding it again?

Comment: I have added a SS of my System.Data properties and it shows v2.0.5 im assuming its looking for only 2.0.0? im not sure.

Comment: Is it a bitness issue? Are you referencing the 64bit when you need the 32bit or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key token you're seeing (`b77a5c....`) indicates that you referenced a desktop assembly.  This will not work for a Compact Framework application.  You must use a SQLite assembly that was specifically built for Windows CE/Compact Framework.  It will have a reference to mscorlib, etc that have a public key token of `969db8...`;

Comment: Yes I checked down at the very bottom of that downloads page and downloaded the Pocket PC version of Sqlite and replaced the .dll file with that and re-referenced it which cleared up my problem. thanks.

Comment: for anyone else out there that finds this as their solution. make sure you copy both Interop.dll and and SQLite.dll. you may get a different named Interop. if so then Remove .xxx from SQLlite.Interop.xxx.DLL. Copy SQLlite.Interop.DLL and System.Data.SQLIte to your project and only reference the SQLite.dll.

Answer (score 0):

It wants the System.Data Version 2.0.0.0. The reference you have is Version 3.5.0.0.

The problem is that there is some other dll in your references which explicitly refrences 2.0.0.0. You need to find it and replace it with a correct version